# How can I delete an sms straight after it is sent on android with SL4A?

Tags: android, python, sms, sl4a, qpython3

I have a small company and I wanted to make a rather simple python3 program that will run on my phone on Qpython3 using SL4A. The purpose of it is to send group SMSs to my customers with offers (whose phone numbers I store in a list) from my personal phone because I have unlimited texts.

I have managed to create a program which sends the texts (relevant fragment below) but the problem is that I have quite a few numbers collected in the list by now. When the texts are sent, a new thread is created for each customer in my messages so I have about 550 threads created each time I send a group sms and I end up deleting them manually which is rather annoying to get to my personal sms threads below.

What I wanted to ask for is help to create a short code fragment whereby the sms sent by the script will be immediately deleted after it is sent so overall, after sending all text messages, no threads relating to these will appear in my messaging app (default samsung galaxy s4 app). Also, is there a way to send the message so that the next message is only sent once the previous one is confirmed as sent (not in the process of sending) because to stop my phone from freezing, I currently just use time.sleep?

```
import androidhelper, time
droid=androidhelper.Android()

#loads of irrelevant code here
#example values of variables numbers and message below
numbers=["0000000001","000000000002","000000000000003"]
message="This is a sample message."

for number in numbers:
    droid.smsSend(number,message)
    #The code below is here so that the texts don't fail to send as they did before I added this in. Hopefully, you could help me to replace it with something to wait for the previous sms to be confirmed as sent.
    time.sleep(3)
```

Please help me with this problem. I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance to anyone who replies.

Comment: Which Android version are you running?

Comment: It's 5.0.2 on a galaxy s4 (i9505)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import sl4a, time
droid=sl4a.Android()
```

and numbers in international format: ['+7989xxxxxxx', '+7961xxxxxxx']
this is work for me in qpython 3

Comment: Thanks. I'll try in a few days when I will be back from holidays

Answer (score 1):

I used this code with no problem:

## Imports

```
import androidhelper, time
import sl4a
```

## Set up sl4a

```
droid = sl4a.Android()
```

## Here you put in a prompting message that will create an empty input to type your message

```
message = droid.dialogGetInput('This text will prompt for the message you want to send').result
```

## Turns what you type in into a StringVariable

```
message = str(message)


numbers = ('phone number one', 'phone number two', 'phone number ETC')
for number in numbers:
     droid.smsSend(number, message)
     time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     droid = sl4a.Android()
```

Comment: Could you rewrite the code inside the code sample (Press Ctrl + K to put it inside code sample i.e. <pre><code> )

Comment: I had to correct one thing, had number and numbers backwards.

Comment: Manishrw, Do I just press Ctrl + k the start typing? I wondered why mine looked different than other peoples.